# $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}, x \neq 0} \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}$ equivalent to $\sup_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

I have seen it mentioned in many places that for some matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$

$\displaystyle\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n, x \neq 0} \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}$
is equivalent to
$\displaystyle\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|$.

I can see why this makes sense intuitively, but it is possible to prove it formally?

Comment: $\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} = \|A \frac{x}{\|x\|} \|$

Comment: This is shown among related questions (in the sidebar on the right): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393794/basic-question-about-sup-x-neq-0-frac-ax-x-sup-x-1 It seems that (at least in some cases) the SE software does a good job in looking for similar questions. (Of course, the credit goes partially to the OP; the fact that they chose specific enough title probably helped a lot.)

Answer (score 0):

Take

$$0\neq x\in\Bbb R^n\;,\;\;u:=\frac x{||x||}$$

then

$$||Au||=\left\|A\left(\frac x{||x||}\right)\right\|\stackrel{\text{linearity}}=\left\|\frac1{||x||}A x\right\|=\frac{||Ax||}{||x||}$$